# How to generate file name without looping

Tags: c#

this way i am looping in two days and generate file name and store in list. so i like to know is there any way by which i can avoid loop but generate file name like looping.

```
    DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
    List<string> filename = new List<string>();

    for (DateTime date = EndDate; date.Date <= StartDate.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
    {
        filename.Add("Report_"+date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+".csv");
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to loop?

Comment: why your end date less than start?

Comment: Using a LINQ statement as proposed by the answers so far looks shorter and more concise but it doesn't improve performance and IMO it also doesn't improve readability but lessens it.

Comment: `filename.Add("Report_"+DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+".csv"); filename.Add("Report_"+DateTime.Now.AddDays(-6).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+".csv"); filename.Add("Report_"+DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+".csv"); [...] filename.Add("Report_"+DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+".csv"); filename.Add("Report_"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+".csv");`

Comment: @NineBerry - Performance? That's not generally an issue for such small lists. Using my solution LINQ can produce over 1,000 dates in under a millisecond.

Comment: @NineBerry - Also, please don't delete comments when they affect a future reader's understanding of the discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this count as no looping?

```
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now;
List<string> filename =
    Enumerable
        .Range(-7, 8)
        .Select(n => "Report_" + StartDate.AddDays(n).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv")
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var filename = new int[8]
    .Select((d, i) => string.Format("Report_{0:dd-MM-yyyy}.csv", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i)))
    .Reverse()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This produces the results backwards.